# How to create a job that runs at a fixed interval in RxJava?

Tags: reactive-programming, rx-java

I'm trying to create a task that will on a regular basis query my database write all the results in an other state and i'd like to do this using RxJava.

I'm using [RxJava-JDBC](https://github.com/davidmoten/rxjava-jdbc) to query my database. Here's what the code looks like:

```java
    final Database db = Database.from(url);

    db
        .select("SELECT f1,f2 FROM mydata")
        .autoMap(MyDatum.class)
        .subscribe(
            new Action1<MyDatum>() {
                @Override
                public void call(MyDatum t) {
                    state.add(t);
                }
            },
            new Action1<Throwable>() {
                @Override
                public void call(Throwable t) {
                    L.error("Task failed", t);
                }
            },
            new Action0() {
                @Override
                public void call() {
                    state.makeAvailable();
                }
            }
        );
```

The thing is this works once when I subscribe then it stops. So i used `Observable.interval` and had this working:

```java
    Observable
        .interval(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .forEach(
            new Action1<Long>() {
                @Override
                public void call(Long arg) {
                    db
                        .select("SELECT f1,f2 FROM mydata")
                        .autoMap(MyDatum.class)
                        .subscribe(
                            new Action1<MyDatum>() {
                                @Override
                                public void call(MyDatum t) {
                                    state.add(t);
                                }
                            },
                            new Action1<Throwable>() {
                                @Override
                                public void call(Throwable t) {
                                    L.error("Task failed", t);
                                }
                            },
                            new Action0() {
                                @Override
                                public void call() {
                                    state.makeAvailable();
                                }
                            }
                        );
                }
            }
        );
```

But I wonder if i'm not doing something wrong having a stream nested in an other.
I thought about using `flatMap` but then the `onComplete` would never be executed as `interval` never calls `onComplete`.

I will want this to evolve and be used triggered not only by an interval but also by incoming events.

Am I missing something here ?
Thanks

Comment: `doOnNext` and `doOnCompleted` operators are very useful in your case. Here is an example how you can implement the described behavior using those operators https://gist.github.com/nsk-mironov/087bbe570a617d366260

Comment: There is a quirk about the `interval` method you are using. It will only kick off after x timeunit has passed. I suggest using `timer(0, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)` which will immediately. See [Github PR](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/pull/2975).

Comment: @VladimirMironov Thanks, that looks indeed a bit better than what i did. Would you mind proposing this as an answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`doOnNext` and `doOnCompleted` operators are very useful in your case. Here is an example how you can implement the described behavior using those operators:

```
final Observable<MyDatum> observable = Observable.interval(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS).flatMap(new Func1<Long, Observable<MyDatum>>() {
    @Override
    public Observable<MyDatum> call(final Long counter) {
        return db.select("SELECT f1,f2 FROM mydata")
                .autoMap(MyDatum.class)
                .doOnNext(new Action1<MyDatum>() {
                    @Override
                    public void call(final MyDatum value) {
                        state.add(value);
                    }
                })
                .doOnCompleted(new Action0() {
                    @Override
                    public void call() {
                        state.makeAvailable();
                    }
                });
    }
});

final Subscription subscription = observable.subscribe();
```

Answer (score 1):

`flatMap` and `merge` are the operators you want to use. Firstly you should avoid subscribing to observables in the body of an operator. Instead use flatMap and return the observable. This will subscribe to all emitted observables for you.

In order to manually trigger a query you can merge in a `PublishSubject` ([documentation](http://reactivex.io/documentation/subject.html)) which you can call `onNext` to push an event and manually trigger the query. Change your code to something like this.

```java
PublishSubject<Long> subject = PublishSubject.create();
Observable.merge(subject, Observable.timer(0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
    .flatMap(new Func1<Long, Observable<MyDatum>>() {
        @Override
        public Observable<MyDatum> call(Long arg) {
            return db
                .select("SELECT f1,f2 FROM mydata")
                .autoMap(MyDatum.class);
    }}).subscribe(
        new Action1<MyDatum>() {
            @Override
            public void call(MyDatum t) {
                state.add(t);
            }
        },
        new Action1<Throwable>() {
            @Override
            public void call(Throwable t) {
                L.error("Task failed", t);
            }
        },
        new Action0() {
            @Override
            public void call() {
                state.makeAvailable();
            }
        }
    );
// you can call onNext with any value to trigger a manual query
subject.onNext(999L);
```

Here is a simple RxJava snippet that demonstrates this behavior.

```java
CountDownLatch l = new CountDownLatch(5);
PublishSubject<Long> subject = PublishSubject.create();
Observable.merge(subject, Observable.timer(0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS).take(3))
        .flatMap((Long arg) -> {
            System.out.println("tick: " + arg);
            l.countDown();
            return Observable.just(arg+10);
        })
        .forEach(System.out::println);
l.await(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
subject.onNext(999L);
l.await();
```

**output**

```
tick: 0
10
tick: 999
1009
tick: 1
11
tick: 2
12
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about PublishSubject. It will probably allow me the external triggering I've been looking for. Concerning the main part of the question though, the reason i didn't use flatMap is, as I said, that the complete action never gets called as the timer never completes. What i would like i guess, is a timer that sends onComplete after every onNext.